# How to access Bootstrap selectpicker value through looping in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to perform a simply required validation using jquery. So I need to access the values of all elements through looping so that I can check values exist or not. Everything works fine except jquery selectpicker. I am trying as follows:

```
// validation
$(document).on('click',"#submitAjaxForm",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var isValid=0;
    $('.required').each(function () {

        // remove border red color from this element
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
        });
        $(this).change(function () {
            $(this).next('span').css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
        });
        $('.selectpicker').on('change', function (e) {
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
            $(this).siblings('.bootstrap-select').css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
        });

        // set border red color to this element
        if ($(this).val())
        {
            isValid=1;
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
            $(this).next('span').css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
        }
        else
        {
            isValid=0;
            $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
            $(this).next('span').css("border", "1px solid red");
        }
    });

    if(isValid)
    {
        $('#partiiSubmit').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Zone<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php echo form_dropdown("zone", $zone, set_value("zone"), "class='select2 form-control required' id='zone' data-tags='true' data-allow-clear='true' data-placeholder='Select zone'"); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Area<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select id="area" name="area" class="select2 form-control required" data-tags="true" data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder="Select Area">
                    <option value=""> Select Area</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Ship/Establishment<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="selectpicker form-control required" data-live-search="true" name="shiftEstablishment[]" id="shift" data-placeholder="Select Ship/Establishment" multiple data-actions-box="true">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Part-II<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="selectpicker form-control required" data-live-search="true" name="partiiName[]" id="partiiID" data-placeholder="Select Part-II Name" multiple data-actions-box="true">
                    <option value="">Select One</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($partii as $row) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row->PartIIID ?>"><?php echo $row->Name ?></option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="submitAjaxForm" value="Submit">
        <input type="hidden" class="btn btn-info" id="partiiSubmit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have improved my question @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: Would be great to add the HTML and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added html@IslamElshobokshy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding the `required` class to `selectpicker` select, so it's not going into the loop so it's normal that it wouldn't work, you need to add the class.

Also your if condition should look like `if ($(this).val() != "")`

```js
$(document).on('click', "#submitAjaxForm", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var isValid = 0;
  $('.required').each(function() {
    // remove border red color from this element
    $(this).keyup(function() {
      $(this).css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
    });
    $(this).change(function() {
      $(this).next('span').css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
    });
    $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(e) {
      $(this).css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
      $(this).siblings('.bootstrap-select').css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
    });

    // set border red color to this element
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      isValid = 1;
      $(this).parent().css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
      $(this).parent().next('span').css("border", "1px solid #ddd");
    } else {
      isValid = 0;
      $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
      $(this).next('span').css("border", "1px solid red");
    }
  });

  if (isValid) {
    $('#partiiSubmit').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.5/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.5/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Zone<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Area<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select id="area" name="area" class="select2 form-control required" data-tags="true" data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder="Select Area">
          <option value=""> Select Area</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Ship/Establishment<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="selectpicker required form-control" data-live-search="true" name="shiftEstablishment[]" id="shift" data-placeholder="Select Ship/Establishment" multiple data-actions-box="true">
          <option value="">no</option>
          <option value="1">test</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Part-II<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="selectpicker required form-control" data-live-search="true" name="partiiName[]" id="partiiID" data-placeholder="Select Part-II Name" multiple data-actions-box="true">
          <option value="">no</option>
          <option value="1">test</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="submitAjaxForm" value="Submit">
    <input type="hidden" class="btn btn-info" id="partiiSubmit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8qx2zr9b/5/

Comment: Please check it again I have updated the question @Islam Elshobokshy

Comment: @BabluAhmed what's not working for you in my code? You updated your question to add things I mentioned and fixed in my answer... Please check the fiddle :-)

Comment: When clicking the submit button it's just showing border color red but how to remove the border color, there are no options set @Islam Elshobokshy

Comment: @BabluAhmed what doesn't? Open the fiddle. Click on submit, everything will be red. Open the middle select, click on "select all", click on submit, the red will go away. You're not having this same result as I do?

Comment: The red color is not removing for `Ship/Establishment` and `Part-II` @Islam Elshobokshy